Uso de useState y useEffect
Estoy creando un login con react y estoy teniendo problemas con el "esconder" el form y luego mostrarlo después de que se inicia sesión, creo que estoy haciendo algo mal con el useState y useEffect


const Admin = () => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);  // Estado inicial como null
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        
        if (token) {
            console.log('Token encontrado:', token);
            setIsAuthenticated(true);  // Usuario autenticado
        } else {
            console.log('No se encontró token.');
            setIsAuthenticated(false);  // Usuario no autenticado
            setTimeout(() => navigate('/login'), 500);  // Redirige después de 500ms
        }
    }, [navigate, isAuthenticated]);

    if (isAuthenticated === null) {
        // Mientras estamos verificando el token
        return <div>Cargando...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <>
            {isAuthenticated ? (
                form que quiero esconder 
            ) : null}
        </>
    );
};

export default Admin;



Este sería donde está el form que quiero esconder, cabe aclarar que también tengo todo importado, es decir el useState y lo demás.
Quisiera me dieran una mano

Hola, que tal? Consulta, a que te refieres con esconder el form? te refieres a navegar hacía otro componente? por ejemplo, al realizar la autentificación deseas navegar hacía el home?

No, digamos que cuando el estado de isAuthenticaded es true entonces que se muestre si es falso entonces que se esconda, con esconder me refiero a que no se muestre o se vea

Tienes una dependencia cíclica en tu useEffect, lo cual es muy desaconsejable. No deberías actualizar el valor de isAuthenticated dentro de un useEffect que depende de si mismo. Por otro lado, lo usual en estos casos es utilizar rutas y un sistema de protección de las mismas y no usar renderizado condicional en tu componente, como el que parece que quieres usar. Por último y no menos importante, usar token para autenticación y almacenar el mismo en el localstorage es una mala práctica. No deberías usar token para autenticación, no está diseñado para eso.

Cuando hablo de autenticación, con JWT (o token) me refiero a que tratas de mantener el estado de la sesión de usuario con un token. Esto no es aconsejable. En cambio, JWT o el token de autenticación podrías considerarlo como una firma de autenticidad, para mostrar que la petición es auténtica. Esto no tiene nada que ver con la validación de sesión de usuario, para saber si ha hecho login o no.

Podríamos hacer un meet? No comprendo muy bien así por mensajes jeje
